# Why Displaying different gradient color on IE but works perfectly on firefox and chrome?

Tags: html, css, gradient

I am working on one of the opensource projects. I am facing a weird problem.  When I open the website on Firefox or Chrome it displays the color I expect, but on IE it does not show up in that color (it shows very light color). My guess is, that this is happening because of the gradient I am using which IE is not able to interpret correctly. Here is gradient CSS code:

```css
#mainmenu {
  #css3_backgroundLinearGradient({
    'angle': 'top',
    'colors': [
      {'color': '#77D3F8', 'position': '0%'},
      {'color': '#3FA4D8', 'position': '100%'}
    ]
  })
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px $theme.linkColor;
}
```

When I do the view source on web page, I also see a line i.e:

```css
  <div class="gradientfilterIE"></div>.
```

I am not sure, is this line the culprit? But the complete open source project
source code does not have this line with `gradientfilterIE`.  I am not sure if this line is causing the issue then where is it coming from?

**I need your expert opinion why I see different gradient color on IE but works perfectly on Firefox and Chrome.**

Setting this actually solved my problem:

```css
#mainmenu .gradientfilterIE {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#77D3F8',     endColorstr='#3FA4D8',GradientType=0 );
}
```

**Do we require `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient` only for IE?
Because on Firefox and Chrome, without this it also works fine.**

Comment: Are you using a CSS compiler like LESS or alike? If so, which one?

Comment: If I might take a wild guess, is this using the Velocity engine for Java? And we were supposed to know by "one of the opensource project" that that's what it is?

Comment: yes it is velocity engine for java. opensource is xwiki. I did not name it , because i did not want the discussion to be directed to xwiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradients only work in modern browsers and not IE but that CSS you show is invalid in the first place.

Comment: Hi rob this css works fine in firefox and chrome. Does not look like there is any issue in css.

Comment: @MSach This CSS only work, because it is compiled before served to a browser. If you would insert this directly into a html document, you would receive many errors and warnings by the CSS parser.

Comment: Thats completely true. sorry,i was not aware of this velocity engine before

Comment: @sirko do we require filter gradient ( filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient ()for IE only as it work on firefox without it?

Comment: @MSach Sorry, I don't have enough experience with CSS filters and gradients to help you here. But the filter you are applying is limited to IE. I don't know, if there is a crossbrowser solution right now.