# Do we require filter gradient ( filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient ()for IE only as gradient effect work on firefox without it?

Tags: html, css, gradient

**Do we require filter gradient ( filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient ()for IE only as it work on firefox without it?**
Setting the below property in css gave me proper gradient effect on IE

```
 #mainmenu .gradientfilterIE {
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#77D3F8',     endColorstr='#3FA4D8',GradientType=0 );
  }
```

**But on Chrome and Firefox it works without it too.**

This question is actually in continuation of [Why Displaying different gradient color on IE but works perfectly on firefox and chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924978/why-displaying-different-gradient-color-on-ie-but-works-perfectly-on-firefox-and)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The `filter` (and `-ms-filter`) CSS properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(v=vs.85).aspx) are *only* supported in Internet Explorer. They’re a Microsoft extension to CSS, and aren’t supported in any other browser

They’re the only non-image way to achieve gradients in Internet Explorer as of version 9 (although [IE 10 should support CSS gradients in some form](http://caniuse.com/#search=gradients)), so they’re required in IE if you want gradients without images.

(Although [as @Jules notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926691/do-we-require-filter-gradient-filter-progiddximagetransform-microsoft-gradie/9927060#comment12917453_9927060), IE 9 does support both SVG images and embedded base-64 encoded images, so you can have gradients in IE 9 without separate image *files*).

Note that Microsoft’s gradient filter is a bit more limited than the various CSS gradient syntaxes, and SVG’s gradient syntax.

Comment: This isn't quite true. IE9 can support gradients using a url reference to an SVG defined gradient as in: background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2Zy....etc. See visualcsstools.com for an app that will automatically generate the equivalent SVG code.

Comment: @Jules: you’re quite right, although technically that’s still an image (albeit an SVG image encoded into the CSS file). Still worth noting though, I’ll amend my answer.

Answer (score 1):

IE filters are not needed on any browser except IE.

Most other browsers support CSS, including CSS3 gradients